# How could I simplify this exponential sum?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, approximation, exponential-sum

I am trying to simplify this function :
$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^M d_j e^{\frac{a_j}{x^2} + \frac{b_j}{x} + c_j}
$$
where $d_j$ and $a_j$ are negative, $c_j$ is positive and the sign of $b_j$ is unknown. Plus, the function is only defined for positive $x$, and $M$ is very large.

I would like to get rid of the sum. I was thinking about approximating it with an integral, but I don't see how I could do so with so many different coefficients depending on $j$.

Any idea? Even a rough approximation would already be interesting.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll certainly still have $4M$ (or $3M$, see below comment)degrees of freedom from the many coefficients ...

Comment: First, let $d_j'=d_je^{c_j}$. Then you sum "only" over $d_j'e^{\frac {a_j}{x^2}+\frac {b_j}x}$.

Comment: Ok good, thanks, but how would I sum that?

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^M d_j e^{\frac{a_j}{x^2} + \frac{b_j}{x} + c_j}
$$
I suppose that $\:a_j \,,\,b_j \,,\,c_j\:$ are known values. If not, one can do nothing.

Let $\quad C_j=\ln(-c_j)\quad$ with $c_j<0$.

$$f(x) = -\sum_{j=1}^M e^{\frac{a_j}{x^2} + \frac{b_j}{x} + C_j}$$
Using non-linear least squares fitting method, find a function $\alpha(\xi)$ so that $\alpha(j)\simeq a_j$ for all $j$.

Same method, find a function $\beta(\xi)$ so that $\beta(j)\simeq b_j$ for all $j$.

Same method, find a function $\gamma(\xi)$ so that $\gamma(j)\simeq C_j$ for all $j$.

Then, approximately :
$$f(x) = -\int_{\xi=1}^M e^{\frac{\alpha(\xi)}{x^2} + \frac{\beta(\xi}{x} + \gamma(\xi)}d\xi$$

The accuracy will be the best if $M$ is large and if the variations of the functions between one point to the next are not too large, that is if $(a_{j+1}-a_j)$ is not too large compared to $a_j$. The same for the $b_j$ and for the $C_j$ .

If the variations of the functions are too large (functions not smooth enough), one have to split the range of $\xi$ into several sub-ranges, in other words to use piecewise functions.

Comment: The coefficients depending on $j$ are not known. I am actually trying to build a model to fit to some data. So isn't there anything I could do? If i manage to put together all the coefficients to form a new variable depending on $j$, independently from x, I could integrate over it, no? (with integral bounds being parameters to fit)

Comment: If the parameters are anything, the function is anything. Good luck for the continuation!

Comment: Ok sorry, I understand what you meant now. The parameters are known, but their expression is really bad, I will have a hard time doing what you proposed! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is not sure that the proposed method is the best for you. The question was how to transform the sum into an approximative integral. That is my answer. But, from your comment, it seems that the problem is in the scope to fit a model to some data. This is a problem of fitting, which is far from being the same thing than only transforming a sum into integral. Optimising the parameters of an integral might be eventually more difficult than optimising the parameters of a sum. I wish you all the best with your work.